# Rewritten CSS computed style issue (wrong page layout)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, computed-style

I am rewriting CSS (don't ask why) in a way that I'm changing the style attributes via HTMLElement.setAttribute method. The problem sometimes occurs when I have computed styles that make no sense. For example (which happens most frequently), div parent has height value smaller than his child div element, in the computed styles. This makes some problems with the desired layout of the page. It is not easy, actually it is very hard, for me to change the algorithm that rewrites CSS, so does anybody know what is the cause of the problem and what would be the most appropriate way to solve it.

My assumption is that somehow some of the changes are not applied, thus I should force the css parser to recompute the values. Did anybody encounter such problem?

Comment: How do you retrieve the computed heights? Could you make a demo of the issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: You really have to show what you're doing for us to help with this; otherwise you're asking for guesses.

Comment: Post was bumped from August 2... didn't realize this when I posted my answer either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are still trying to display your container at the height that you specify, even if it is smaller than the content that is inside it, you should use the `overflow` property.

`overflow: hidden` will cause the extra content to disappear.

`overflow: auto` will add a scrollbar to the container to allow you to scroll in the container.